# How Do I create multiple gridview programatically

Tags: android

```
public class Dues extends Activity {

    static final String[] alphabets = new String[] { 
            "A", "B", "C", "D"};

    static final String[] alphabets1 = new String[] { 
            "E", "F", "G", "H"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dues);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alphabets);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alphabets1);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        GridView gridView= new GridView(this);

        gridView.setLayoutParams(new 
                      GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        gridView.setNumColumns(4);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg); 

        gridView.setBackground(myIcon);

        GridView gridView1 = new GridView(this);

        gridView1.setLayoutParams(new
                        GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 

        gridView1.setNumColumns(4);

        gridView1.setAdapter(adapter);


        Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg); 

        gridView1.setBackground(myIcon);

    }
}
```

So this code is creating 2 gridviews but its overlapping. Please Help me.
ABCD and EFGH both are overlapping each other. 
Like this I want to add multiple Gridview Using Scrollview .
Can anyone help me with this please.
I want it to be visible one below the other.

The number of gridview is dynamic , there is nor fixed number, Hence I want it to programmatically created and not through xml file.
also I want it to be greenish transparent , so anyone could help me with that too

Answer (score 1):

A `GridView` is scrollable, therefore you cannot achieve what you want with a regular `ScrollView`. Another problem is that you are creating two `GridView`, but you are not adding them to any parent. What you need to do is to create a `NestedScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` in it with `orientation=vertical` and add each `GridView` to it. Apply `match_parent` to both the `NestedScrollView` and `LinearLayout` height and width. Another note, don't use `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` for the `GridView` height, use `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Comment: Oh ok!,Thanks a lot. I did wrap_content but then the gridview is not visible

Comment: Follow step by step what I said. You can not use a ScrollView to achieve this, you must use a NestedScrollView